# Should I keep using document.ready Jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, document

I Have the below code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('td.rightImage, .leftImage a').click(function(){
   if($(this).attr( "id" )){
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'sidebanner', 'click', $(this).attr('id'),0,true]);
   }
 else{
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'sidebanner', 'click', $(this).attr('href'),0,true]);
 }
 });
 });

    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[href$='.pdf']").click(function(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'pdf', 'click',$(this).attr('href'),0,true]);
    });
    });
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[href$='.zip']").click (function(){
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'zip', 'download',$(this).attr('href'),0,true]);
    });
    });
```

Should I keep using docment ready for each onclick event I want?If not what is a better way to code the above?

Thanks

Comment: Make it just one function, they're all called at the same time, afterall.

Comment: Yup! It doesn't matter if you use jQuery or other framework or plain JS. Just remember to execute this kind of code when all elements are already on their places which in jQuery mean `document.ready()`. Your script gets executed as soon as it's available - even before the HTML documet is loaded - that's what `document.ready` or `body.onload` stand for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use on document.ready

```
//OR
//$(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.rightImage, .leftImage a').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("id")) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'sidebanner', 'click', $(this).attr('id'), 0, true]);
        } else {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'sidebanner', 'click', $(this).attr('href'), 0, true]);
        }
    });
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").click(function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'pdf', 'click', $(this).attr('href'), 0, true]);
    });
    $("a[href$='.zip']").click(function () {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'zip', 'download', $(this).attr('href'), 0, true]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way - put them all in ONE DOM ready event.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them and $(document).ready can be written like.

```
$(function(){
   // DOM Ready - do your stuff 
});
```